# Extra locations are targeted while boosting on Meta business suite

Tags: facebook, facebook-ads, meta-business-suite

I am working with a client, publishing and boosting articles for him. Everything is working fine but there is a problem with setting the target locations. I need to target a single location but when click on save button, there are two or three extra locations also added (which are from my previous history). An example is in the screenshot below. I need to target only Richmond, but a few more locations are also targeted.
I tried clearing browsing data, changing browser, trying again and again to remove the extra locations but none of them helped.
I am really in need of help in this regard.

[image]